# How can I use command line in Mac to send email?

Tags: mac, command-line, email

Can I do something like the Unix

"mail ... "

in Mac OS? Are there any plugins or modules to do this?

And if I have a mult-mail account in iMail, can I specify the sender account? 
I am not sure the default Mac iMail is related or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK osx comes with postfix as an smtpd, so if you configure that all should work like a normal *nix box.

EDIT: google turns out this
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081217161612647